# Conditionally replacing Int64 field in DataFrame with month of Int64 field plus Datetime64[ns] field

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, math, pandas

I am running Windows 10, Python 2.7 through the Spyder IDE.

I have a pandas `DataFrame` called `df`:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
tee = pd.date_range('2000-01-01','2005-01-01',freq = 'M')
owe = pd.date_range('2000-01-01','2005-02-29')
eye = random.sample(range(100), 60)
you = random.sample(range(100), 60)
df = pd.DataFrame({'tee': tee , 'owe':owe, 'eye': eye,'you': you})
#df.dtypes
#dtypes: eye and owe = 'datetime64[ns]' , you and tee = 'int64'
```

`you` is measured in days.

For each row that has `tee` in the year 2004, I would like to replace records of `eye` with the month (as format `int64`) of that row's `owe` plus `you`.

Comment: Your code isn't correct. There is no date with 2005-02-29 .. And size of the arrays which you're passing to `pd.DataFrame` should be with equal size. Edit your code properly, please

Comment: And in addition, `tee` and `owe` will have different lengths, causing problems when constructing the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments says about some errors. So I change creating `dataframe` and then apply condition by function [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and [`Series.dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html):

**Notice**: After testing change column name `eye_new` to `eye` in function `loc` !

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

tee = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('2000-01-01'),pd.to_datetime('2005-01-01'),freq = 'M')
owe = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('2000-01-01'),pd.to_datetime('2005-02-28'))
eye = random.sample(range(100), 60)
#http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html
you = np.random.randint(0, 100 , size=1886)

print len(tee)  #60
print len(owe)  #1886
print len(eye)  #60
print len(you)  #1886

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'tee': tee , 'eye': eye})
print df1.head()

   eye        tee
0   17 2000-01-31
1   71 2000-02-29
2   56 2000-03-31
3    2 2000-04-30
4   92 2000-05-31

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'owe':owe, 'you': you})
print df2.head()

         owe  you
0 2000-01-01   78
1 2000-01-02   76
2 2000-01-03   78
3 2000-01-04   51
4 2000-01-05   66
```

```
#merging df1 and df2 by colum,ns tee and owe
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='tee', right_on='owe')

#after testing change eye_new to eye  
result.loc[ result['tee'].dt.year == 2004 ,'eye_new'] = result['owe'].dt.month + 
                                                        result['you']
```

```
print result

    eye        tee        owe  you  eye_new
0    17 2000-01-31 2000-01-31    4      NaN
1    71 2000-02-29 2000-02-29   27      NaN
2    56 2000-03-31 2000-03-31   14      NaN
3     2 2000-04-30 2000-04-30   13      NaN
4    92 2000-05-31 2000-05-31   10      NaN
5    11 2000-06-30 2000-06-30   54      NaN
6    93 2000-07-31 2000-07-31   54      NaN
...
45   49 2003-10-31 2003-10-31   50      NaN
46   79 2003-11-30 2003-11-30   93      NaN
47   68 2003-12-31 2003-12-31   20      NaN
48   96 2004-01-31 2004-01-31   49       50
49   53 2004-02-29 2004-02-29   24       26
50   83 2004-03-31 2004-03-31   56       59
51   39 2004-04-30 2004-04-30   18       22
52   40 2004-05-31 2004-05-31    4        9
53   86 2004-06-30 2004-06-30   42       48
54   48 2004-07-31 2004-07-31   76       83
55    9 2004-08-31 2004-08-31   21       29
56   89 2004-09-30 2004-09-30   24       33
57   18 2004-10-31 2004-10-31   32       42
58   13 2004-11-30 2004-11-30   58       69
59   12 2004-12-31 2004-12-31    6       18
```

EDIT by comments:

```
#after testing change eye_new to eye  
result.loc[ result['tee'].dt.year == 2004 ,'eye_new'] = result.apply(lambda x: x['owe'] + 
                                               pd.DateOffset(days=x['you']), axis=1).dt.month
print result     


    eye        tee        owe  you  eye_new
0     5 2000-01-31 2000-01-31  149      NaN
1    81 2000-02-29 2000-02-29    5      NaN
2    42 2000-03-31 2000-03-31   39      NaN

.
.
.
47   56 2003-12-31 2003-12-31   74      NaN
48   64 2004-01-31 2004-01-31   39        3
49    0 2004-02-29 2004-02-29  395        3
50   13 2004-03-31 2004-03-31  257       12
51   31 2004-04-30 2004-04-30  164       10
52   14 2004-05-31 2004-05-31  116        9
53   37 2004-06-30 2004-06-30  335        5
54   49 2004-07-31 2004-07-31  158        1
55   95 2004-08-31 2004-08-31  244        5
56   82 2004-09-30 2004-09-30  279        7
57   38 2004-10-31 2004-10-31   20       11
58   74 2004-11-30 2004-11-30   33        1
59   59 2004-12-31 2004-12-31  326       11
```

Comment: sorry I was not more clear. Your answer is correct for the question I asked. But I am looking for `eye_new` = month(`owe` + `you`)  not `eye_new` = month(`owe`) + `you`. Can you help here?

Comment: but if `you` is measured in days, then we are adding days to a `owe`, which is timestamp. Wouldn't that make `owe` a larger date? For example (365 days plus 2000-01-01 = 2001-01-01 ; 356 +2000-01-01 = 2001-01-01)

Comment: Thanks @jezrael but `eye_new` should be `dtype int64`, and be the month of the `eye_new` you have in your edited answer. The `eye_new` column in your edited answer is {`2004-04-06`, `2004-05-08`, `2004-04-13`, `2004-07-22`, etc} but it should be {`4`,`5`,`4`,`7`,etc}.